# Show that union of a set A and derived set of A (all accumulation points) is closure of A?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(M,d)$ be a metric space. For a set $A$ in $M$, a point $p$ in $M$ is an accumulation point if there exists a sequence $(x_n)$ of distinct points in $A$ such that $x_n \rightarrow p$. The set of all accumulation points of $A$ is called the derived set of $A$, denoted by $A'$. Show that
$$
\bar{A} = A \cup A'
$$

It is straight forward to show that a point $p \in \bar{A}$ is in $A \cup A'$, i.e., $p \in \bar{A} \subseteq A \cup A'$. Because from the definition of closure we have

$\bar{A}=\{x^* \in M \mid \exists\,\, (x_n)\in A, x_n \rightarrow x^* \in \,(M,d) \}$.

Let $p \in \bar{A}$ so it is either in $A$ or $A'$.

How can we show the reverse?
$$
 A \cup A' \subseteq \bar{A}
$$

Answer (score 1):

$A\subset \bar A$ as $\bar A$ is the smallest closed set *containing* $A$.  Also, $A'\subset \bar A$, because if $(x_n)\in A$ with $x_n\to x$, then $(x_n)\in\bar A\implies x\in\bar A$, since $\bar A$ is closed.